# Im having trouble with selecting data from database using like and order by

Tags: php, pdo, sql-order-by, sql-like

Im making a filter where you can select colors and select newest. It would filter them, but the order by doesn't work for some reason.

I tried it this way. It outputs the colors that match the database table, but it doesn't sort them by date.

```
$color_arr = ["red", "blue", "white"];

foreach($color_arr as $color) {
    $data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `prod_items` WHERE item_color LIKE '%$color%' ORDER BY `item_date` DESC");
    while ($row = $data->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't run sql query inside loop.

```
$sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $color_arr is empty

$color_arr = ["red", "blue", "white"];
foreach($color_arr as $color){
    $sql[] = 'item_color LIKE "%'.$color.'%"';
}

$sql1 = implode(" OR ", $sql). " ORDER BY `item_date` DESC";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE $sql1"; 

$data = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $data->fetch_array()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: That would return completely different results, why replace the `LIKE` part?

Answer (score 0):

You can order by multiple fields, below is the MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `prod_items` WHERE item_color LIKE '%$color%' ORDER BY `item_date` DESC, `price` DESC"
```

This will first sort by item_date and then by price.